# Add total excl. tax line to order totals on Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sum, email-notifications

I am looking for a way to add an extra row in my woocommerce order mails, with a subtotal including shipping excluding taxes (or VAT). This row i want to have before the Taxes. (this should be a calculation of the sum of productcosts+shipping costs)

as it's a calculation, it should be something like  $get_total_excl_taxes = $order->get_total() - $order->get_total_tax();

I should paste this into the child-theme email-order-details.php i assume. However where I do this, It doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
        $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals();

        if ( $totals ) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                $i++;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['label'] ); ?></th>
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['value'] ); ?></td>

                    <here??>

                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Note:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ) ); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will add a new row with the total excluding VAT in the totals on email notifications:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'add_order_total_excl_vat_row', 10, 3 );
function add_order_total_excl_vat_row( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    // Only on emails notifications
    if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() || ! is_admin() ) {

        // Set last total row in a variable and remove it.
        $gran_total = $total_rows['order_total'];
        unset( $total_rows['order_total'] );

        // Insert our new row
        $total_rows['order_total_ev'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Total Excl. VAT :', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => wc_price( $order->get_total() - $order->get_total_tax() ),
        );

        // Set back last total row
        $total_rows['order_total'] = $gran_total;
    }

    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

To add this new line before Tax line (when it's enabled in tax settings) use this instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'custom_order_total_excl_vat_row', 10, 3 );
function custom_order_total_excl_vat_row( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    // Only on emails notifications
    if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() || ! is_admin() ) {

        $new_total_rows = array();

        // Loop through total lines
        foreach( $total_rows as $key => $values ){
            if( $key === 'tax' ){
                $new_total_rows['order_total_et'] = array(
                    'label' => __( 'Total Excl. VAT :', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'value' => wc_price( $order->get_total() - $order->get_total_tax() ),
                );
            }
            $new_total_rows[$key] = $values;
        }

        return $new_total_rows;
    }

    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: this works great, thank you so much. only thing which would be nice if it could be placed before the taxes instead of after. is that possible?

Comment: I just checked, and works great. Thanks again. It only shows up at the order-received page (after confirming the order). it should be only in the emails right? i'll mark this as answered of course! thanks!